Getting rid of Big-M notation
i have the following constraint using the Big-$M$ method and i was wondering if it is possible to formulate these constraints without Big-$M$. These are the constraints in question:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{t}z_{ij}\le \omega + M\cdot z^{m}_{it} \quad \forall i,t$$
$$\omega + m\le \sum_{j=1}^{t}z_{ij}+(1-z^{m}_{it})\cdot M\quad \forall i, t$$
$$(1-o_{it})\le (1-z^{f}_{i(d-1)})+\sum_{j=t-T_M}^{t-1}z_{ij}\quad \forall i, t\in \{1+T_M,...,T\}$$
$$M\cdot (1-o_{it})\ge (1-z^{f}_{i(t-1)})+\sum_{j=t-T_M}^{t-1}z_{ij}\quad \forall i, t\in \{1+T_M,...,T\}$$
In this, $i$ and $t$ are the indicies. The variables $z_{it}, z_{it}^f, z_{it}^m$ and $o_{it}$ are binary, whereas $T_M$ and $\omega$ are integer. Obviusoly, there are also Big-$M$ and Small-$m$.

Would you elaborate more on the second and third constraints? What is $m$ meaning? Is it an $LB$ or something else? Also, is it possible to write what you are trying to linearize in the logical format? (e.g. if $z_{i,t}^m = 0 \implies \sum_{j} z_{i,j} \leq w$)

$m$ is just a small constant, like 0.001 f.e. Regarding the second question, yes, thats the correct logical format.

Sure. I fixed it!

Assume without loss of generality that $M$ is an integer. The right side of your second constraint ($\omega + m \le \dots$) is integer, so if it has to be greater than or equal to $\omega + 0.001$ then it has to be greater than or equal to $\omega + 1,$ the next integer after $\omega.$ So you can set $m=1.$
The maximum value of the left side of your first constraint is $t,$ so you can set $M=t$ there (assuming that $\omega \ge 0$). For the second constraint, you would need $M$ to be an upper bound on $\omega + 1.$
For the last constraint, the right side is no bigger than $T_M + 1,$ so that is a suitable value for $M.$ (Also, you owe us 30 pushups for using $M$ as both a large constant and the subscript of $T$.)
